# CF : Local Reads MBean for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, jmx, datastax, jolokia

I am using JMX MBeans for monitoring Cassandra metrics. I am looking to enable CF : Local Reads equivalent in opscenter, does anyone know what is the equivalent JMX Mbean for it?

Answer (score 0):

The metrics are listed out here: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#table-metrics

The ReadLatency mbean on the table metrics so: `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=YOURKEYSPACE,scope=YOURTABLE,name=ReadLatency`
 or `type=ColumnFamily` for older versions of C*.

OpsCenter uses the `values` operation to get the raw histogram so it may look slightly different than when reading the mbeans directly, but the decaying histogram is less accurate when monitoring over time so going based on raw values is better. It is described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcniEFmFY0E) presentation.